# How to make a single Expression execute the contents of a method?

Tags: c#

I've created an `Expression` which is defined by passing a variable to a method. The `Expression` is ultimately passed to another method. (as depicted below)

The problem I have is it's throwing an exception:

> variable 'x' of type 'JobDefinitions.Interfaces.IBackgroundJobDefinitions' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

I don't understand this. Why can't I pass a parameter to a method? If I remove the method call and use the parameter directly, it works fine e.g.

```
Expression<Action<IBackgroundJobDefinitions>> myExpression = x => x.FetchCorporateActionsDaily();
```

but putting that functionality into a method results in the exception, e.g.

```
Expression<Action<IBackgroundJobDefinitions>> myExpression = x =>  ExecuteTwoJobs(x);
```

Other explanations I've seen for this error have related to attempts to create 2 similar `Expressions`, with the reason being the compiler creates different expressions. But that doesn't apply in this case because there is only 1 `Expression`.

How can I get the `Expression` to behave in the way that allows me to run the `ExecuteTwoJobs` method?

[image]

Comment: "variable 'x' of type 'JobDefinitions.Interfaces.IBackgroundJobDefinitions' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined" Something has messed up the expression trees? If you renamed your parameters, they might look like `x1 =>  ExecuteTwoJobs(x2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move the Expression into its own class

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code but the code itself in your answer